# Saving whole instance of an activity

Tags: android, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

Is there any simple way to save the whole activity instance and restoring it ? 
After spending 1 hour of searching all corners of internet, I ended up here. I still don't know how to make this.

Yes, I know how to save current instance using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`
**but no one in the internet explained it with a large complex coding like dynamically created views, many textviews and calculations,etc.** 
Everyone explaining this with only one or two textViews and I was like *"How someone can create an app with only few TextViews!?!"* like below:

**onSaveInstanceState()**

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    
    final EditText textBox = 
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    CharSequence userText = textBox.getText();
    outState.putCharSequence("savedText", userText);

}
```

**onRestoreInstanceState()**

```
    @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
   Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");

   final EditText textBox =
        (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

   CharSequence userText =
                savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("savedText");

   textBox.setText(userText);
}
```

I can totally understand this above method. But What to do if we complete a quite complicated coding and want to save & restore the state I have completed all my complex coding stuff and landed in this problem. 
I'm sure there will be a simple way to achieve this. Please understand my problem. Help me.

Comment: Interesting question. How complex is your view? Basically you should only save the state/data of your activity/view and restore its view based on the restored state/data. If your view takes too long to be restored, maybe its worth trying to improve the view-hierarchie then.

Comment: Okay. Imagine this,  there's a button that inflates a row of textviews in a linearLayout from another layout file in an onClick event. That row may contain any number of views depending on the another user input, say for example Spinner item. See, It's already getting complicated. This complexity is nothing when compared to real thing.... :)

Comment: I would investigate if it's worth migrating your logic of inflating the view from a data model. On any event (like a click), you generate a new data model. Then you can create your view from that data model. And you can save and restore that data model at any time.

Comment: android studio is an IDE, it just helps you to code. your app isn't any different because you're using android studio to develop it, so unless you have a question specifically related to android-studio, please don't use the android-studio tag

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to save the current state of the page even the page changes, if this is the case, it can be solved by data binding as follows:

1.enable data binding in Gradle

2. in XML file put your layout into layout tag

```
<layout>
 ...// your activity view layout
</layout>
```

3. then define it in your activity :

   private lateinit var binding: FragmentNameBinding

4.add this expression in onCreate or onCreateView(for fragment)

```
if (!(::binding.isInitialized)) {
  //initialize you layout file and what ever you want 
   }
  //then initialize what you want to not change  after the layout 
  changed and back to it
```